# error during connect: Get "http://direct.labs.play-with-docker.com:2375/v1.24/containers/json": EOF

Tags: docker

I'm using docker context and i successfully created a context called pwd.

```
➜  ~ docker context create --docker "host=tcp://ip172-18-0-89-c5e2kunnjsv000dgin8g@direct.labs.play-with-docker.com:2375" pwd
pwd
Successfully created context "pwd"
```

Now i switch to it with `docker context use pwd` and its brings back `pwd` which means i'm now using pwd.

```
➜  ~ docker context use pwd 
pwd
```

so now if i type `docker context ls` it returned this:

```
➜  ~ docker context ls
NAME                TYPE                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT                                                                  KUBERNETES ENDPOINT   ORCHESTRATOR
default             moby                Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock                                                                            swarm
desktop-linux       moby                                                          unix:///Users/ali/.docker/run/docker.sock                                                              
pwd *               moby                                                          tcp://ip172-18-0-89-c5e2kunnjsv000dgin8g@direct.labs.play-with-docker.com:2375
```

so now i'm in pwd!

but if i type `docker ps` for instance, or any command it returned an single error:

```
error during connect: Get "http://direct.labs.play-with-docker.com:2375/v1.24/containers/json": EOF
```

whats wrongs?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i found the answer!
the error occurred because of the first line(create context):

the ssh address that [PWD](https://labs.play-with-docker.com/)(play with docker) gives us is:

```
ssh ip172-18-0-89-c5e2kunnjsv000dgin8g@direct.labs.play-with-docker.com
```

and for creating a context we use this command:

```
➜  ~ docker context create --docker "host=tcp://ip172-18-0-89-c5e2kunnjsv000dgin8g@direct.labs.play-with-docker.com:2375" pwd
```

but the trick is we should replace `@` with `.` ...
so the command should be like this:

```
➜  ~ docker context create --docker "host=tcp://ip172-18-0-89-c5e2kunnjsv000dgin8g.direct.labs.play-with-docker.com:2375" pwd
```

and now it works like charms!

for example:

```
➜  ~ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                  NAMES
3f6cf27f5a09   nginx     "/docker-entrypoint.…"   26 minutes ago   Up 25 minutes   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   web
```